# how to set decimal places to 0 when using currencies

Tags: iphone, decimal, currency, nsnumberformatter

In my application ,I am handling large numbers(currencies) and I am formatting them using nsnumberformatter.however currently ,the number of decimal places are set according to the locale.Since large numbers are involved ,i dont want to display the decimal places in any currency. how to set the decimal places to zero in nsnumberformatter currency style?

code used

```
NSDecimalNumber *someAmount = [NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithString:unformattedString];
    NSNumberFormatter *currencyFormatter = [[[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init] autorelease];
    [currencyFormatter setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterCurrencyStyle];
    [currencyFormatter setLocale:locale];
    NSString *str=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.0f",someAmount];
    //NSString *str=[currencyFormatter stringFromNumber:someAmount];
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use the code below to remove the decimal places from the number formatter:

```
[currencyFormatter setMaximumFractionDigits:0];
```

Full code using your code above:

```
NSDecimalNumber *someAmount = [NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithString:unformattedString];
NSNumberFormatter *currencyFormatter = [[[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init] autorelease];
[currencyFormatter setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterCurrencyStyle];
[currencyFormatter setLocale:locale];
[currencyFormatter setMaximumFractionDigits:0];
NSString *str=[currencyFormatter stringFromNumber:someAmount];
```

Comment: Is it possible to see your code that is formatting the number.

Comment: i wer using the commented code ,now i changed it as suggested

Comment: I've just edited my answer, you need to set the MaximumFractionDigits on your number formatter to 0

Comment: Is it possible to remove the decimals only when price is 3,00, i.e., all decimals are zero?